# Issue related to ItemCommand event in DataGrid asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp.net application having DataGrid on the aspx page having some autogenerated columns :

i have bound ItemCommand Event on the grid  as Following :

```
 protected void DataGrid2_ItemCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "CheckInventoryAndPrice")
            {


                string itemMainPageLink = E2WConstants.Pages.ITEM_MAIN;
                string itemId = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["ItemId"].ToString();

                //Response.Redirect();
            }
        }
```

but i am getting  DataItem Null always :  so how can i get the value of cell of selected row ??

Thanks..